# New svn repository script

Tags: bash

This is my very first Bash script that does something real. I'm here to learn, so please tell me if and how this can be done better.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Daniele Brugnara
# October - 2013

if [ -k $1 ]; then
        echo "Error! You must pass a repository name!"
        exit 1
fi

SVN_PATH="/var/lib/svn"
currPath=$(pwd)

cd $SVN_PATH
svnadmin create $1
chown -R www-data:www-data $1
cd $currPath

echo "Done! Remember to set valid user permission in authz file."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the first argument to your script contains a space, then you get an error message:

   ```
   $ ./cr32076.sh "my repository"
   ./cr32076.sh: line 6: [: my: binary operator expected
   ```

   To avoid this, put quotes around the variable `$1`, like this:

   ```
   if [ -k "$1" ]; then
   ```
2. The [man page for `[`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/test/) says:

   ```
   -k file       True if file exists and its sticky bit is set.
   ```

   is this really what you mean? It seems more likely that you want the `-z` option:

   ```
   -z string     True if the length of string is zero.
   ```
3. You remember the current directory in a variable:

   ```
   currPath=$(pwd)
   ```

   and then later change to it:

   ```
   cd $currPath
   ```

   but this will go wrong if the current directory has a space in its name:

   ```
   $ pwd
   /Users/gdr/some directory
   $ currPath=$(pwd)
   $ cd $currPath
   bash: cd: /Users/gdr/some: No such file or directory
   ```

   To avoid this, put quotes around the variable, like this:

   ```
   cd "$currPath"
   ```
4. If you want to change directory temporarily and change back again, then instead of writing

   ```
   currPath=$(pwd)   # remember old directory
   cd "$SVN_PATH"    # change to new directory
   # do some stuff
   cd "$currPath"    # go back to old directory
   ```

   you can use a [*subshell*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping):

   ```
   (
       cd "$SVN_PATH"    # change to new directory
       # do some stuff        
   ) # old directory is automatically restored when subshell exits
   ```

   But in this script, there's no need to change directory back again, because after you go back all you do is `echo "Done! ..."` and it doesn't matter what directory you do that in.
5. In fact, there's no need to change directory at all, because instead of

   ```
   SVN_PATH="/var/lib/svn"
   currPath=$(pwd)

   cd "$SVN_PATH"
   svnadmin create "$1"
   chown -R www-data:www-data "$1"
   cd "$currPath"
   ```

   you could write

   ```
   SVN_PATH="/var/lib/svn/$1"
   svnadmin create "$SVN_PATH"
   chown -R www-data:www-data "$SVN_PATH"
   ```